# dynamically added form field didn't post when form submitted

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit

I have a problem with dynamically appended form elements.

I have used this code to append form elements

```
$('#wrap_range_'+id).append("<div style='clear:both; margin:0;'></div>
    <select name='range_"+id+"[]'> 
    <option value=''>--  Select range  --</option>
    <?php
for($cnt=10; $cnt<500; $cnt+=10) {
    echo '<option value=\"'. ($cnt-10) . '-' . $cnt.'\">'. ($cnt-10)  . ' - ' . $cnt .'</option>';         }              
    ?>
    </select>           &nbsp;          
    <input type='text' name='range_discount_"+id+"[]' >
    ");
```

the forn elements are appended successfully, the name attribute of the fields are as i require.

But the problem is that  **when the form submits the dynamically appended elements are not being posted.**

Please guide me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code seems garbled...can you paste it again?

Comment: sure. $('#wrap_range_'+id).append("<div style='clear:both; margin:0;'></div><select name='range_"+id+"[]'>            <option value=''>--  Select quantity range  --</option>              <?php               for($cnt=10; $cnt<500; $cnt+=10) {      echo '<option value=\"'. ($cnt-10) . '-' . $cnt.'\">'. ($cnt-10)  . ' - ' . $cnt .'</option>';      }     ?>           </select>           &nbsp;           <input type='text' name='range_discount_"+id+"[]' >");

Comment: In your PHP code, your only create a list of numbers. Why don't you do that in JS? I bet this mixture breaks it somehow, and it is very very difficult to maintain and debug it.

Comment: Can you please tell me whats the problem submitting the appended elements?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer but I can't seem to comment. What is wrap_range+id. Is it the form or a div or span inside the form? If it isn't the form make sure that it is between the  and . Also how do you know that they're not submitting i.e. what are you doing that you expect values in the dynamically added fields and are not getting them?

Comment: wrap_range+id is a div id. I am posting form and getting them by php post predefined variable

Comment: Are you echoing the results or storing them in a database? And is the div enclosed by the form? Try var_dump($_POST) to see exactly what is in it.